# Can a UICollectionViewLayout have supplementary view in front of cell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm aiming to have a static header with the cells passing underneath as the user scrolls. 
I've created the functionality I'm looking for, however if the supplementary views have a high zIndex than the cell, it blocks the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` method.

Is there a way to work around this?

Here's an example of what I'm after;
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Just incase anyone else stumbles upon this;
You need to set the `userInteractionEnabled`to `NO`.
Thank you.